# Failed to convert parameter value from a TextBox to a Int32

Tags: sql, vb.net

With work being slow I have decided to experiment and learn with Visual Basic. I have decided that it would be nice to develop and app to query my SCCM DB for Bitlocker Keys using a Computer Name as search criteria. My SQL Query works if run vis SQL Studio but I get the following error.

I believe my error is with the two lines of code in bold and my search criteria via a TextBox is typed by the user as LAP-123AB456. Once the user types the computername the user then clicks a button.

ERROR:Failed to convert parameter value from a TextBox to a Int32.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Code Snipit:

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select a.Id, a.Name, b.VolumeId, c.RecoveryKeyId, c.RecoveryKey, c.LastUpdateTime, c.Disclosed from RecoveryAndHardwareCore_Machines a inner join RecoveryAndHardwareCore_Machines_Volumes b ON a.Id = b.MachineId inner join RecoveryAndHardwareCore_Keys c ON b.VolumeId = c.VolumeId where a.name = @entry", connection)
            
    **cmd.Parameters.Add("@entry", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CObj(TXT_ComputerName)**
    
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    
    **Dim table As New DataTable()**
    
    adapter.Fill(table)
```

Error Details:

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Failed to convert parameter value from a TextBox to a Int32.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetCoercedValue()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildParamList(TdsParser parser, SqlParameterCollection parameters, Boolean includeReturnValue)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildExecuteSql(CommandBehavior behavior, String commandText, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at TervitaBitlockerLookup.FRM_BitlockerSearch.BTN_Search_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\admin\source\repos\BitlockerLookup\BitlockerLookup\BitlockerSearch.vb:line 12
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at TervitaBitlockerLookup.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
```

Comment: Why do you try to bind string value and explicitly declare parameter type as Int?

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@entry", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TXT_ComputerName.Text)`, assuming `TXT_ComputerName` is a WinForms' TextBox control. BTW, you should `Integer.TryParse()` it beforehand, for validation. BUT, it doesn't look like that TextBox contains a value that can be converted to an Integer: it looks like, from the names of the Field and the TextBox (`a.name` and `TXT_ComputerName`), it's something completely different, a string that contains the name of something. Check the DB data type.

Comment: Thank you for the help, "a.name" refers to a nvarchar(63) Data Type. This field in the database contains computernames (EG: LAP-AB123CD456). My hope is to allow the user to type a computer name and subit for the results of the SQL query.

Comment: Sorry Hit Enter and it submitted the reply. 

As you suggested if I understood correctly I changed CObj to CInt and I have the following error. Error: "Conversion from string ""lap-pc12"" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

Not sure what you mean about the Integer.TryParse() or where to put that in the code.

Comment: `a.name` is of `nvarchar` type, so you have to provide a string value, not an Integer and specify `SqlDbType.NVarChar`. You can (or should, in code, also specify the length, to be specific and to let other devs see the exact Field specs)

Comment: Ok ... it seems you have put me on the path to success ... I changed the line in question to cmd.Parameters.Add("@entry", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TXT_ComputerName.Text and it no longer gives my the error. Thank you


But it seems I have more code learning to do as if I search for a computername that I know doesn't exist the Else Statement works which is good but if I search for a computername that does exist the app closes with code 0. 

Nore troubleshooting a head for me

Comment: I figured out the last of my issues. Thank you again Jimi for the help.